Setting values for IntVar for CP-SAT solver from OR-Tools
I am currently using a google OR-tools CP-SAT solver for a planification problem. I am using IntVars as a representation of the date. All those IntVars are in a dictionary. I have a few constraints that work correctly but I would like to force the solver to have about 2/3 of my Intvars inferior to 400.
I've tried to solve the problem using BoolVars but didn't succeed and I ran out of ideas of how to force 2/3 of the values under 400.
Can anyone think of a solution?

I am not sure this is a good business rule,
anyway
  int_vars = [...]
  bool_vars = []
  for v in int_vars:
    is_less_than_400 = model.new_bool_var('')
    model.add(v <= 400).only_enforce_if(is_less_than_400)
    model.add(v > 400).only_enforce_if(~is_less_than_400)
    bool_vars.append(is_less_than_400)

  threshold = len(bool_var) * 2 // 3
  model.add(sum(bool_vars) <= threshold)


Thanks a lot, it worked for me, sorry for the poor explaining of the problem, i am a beginner user of your tool.
